# WPF XamDataGrid: What events fire when a user has moved or resized a column

Tags: wpf, xamdatagrid

WPF XamDataGrid: What events fire when a user has moved or resized a column?

I would like to know if the user has done either of these things so that I can save details of the column positions and widths.  Then, when the user opens the grid at a later point, I can restore his chosen column widths and relative positions.

Answer (score 0):

XamDataGrid.FieldPositionChanged/Changing will tell you when a field moves.  Then you use ActualPosition property of the Field from the event args to get its new position.

I haven't found a public event for the Width changing yet, but Field.OnPropertyChanged("Width") is fired.